# Fancybox is not looping properly with ERB in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fancybox, erb

Prior to posting this question, I have tried searching for the answer to no avail. What I am trying to accomplish seems fairly simple, but the answer evades me. I am using fancybox to generate a modal window of an image gallery with images stored in my postgres database under the modeling model (sorry for the poor naming convention). Below is the snippet of code that I am currently running:

```
<div class="row small-11 small-centered columns">
 <% @modelings.each do |modeling| %>
  <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<%= modeling.image %>">
   <div class="small-11 small-centered columns banner" id="banner1">
    <h1>EXPRESSIONS</h1>
   </div>
  </a>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

I am using ZURB's foundation which should not have any issues with the fancybox(at least I think). The `<div ... id="banner1">` is the the div I want to onclick trigger the fancybox's modal window. This div contains an image rendered through my CSS.

```
#banner1 {
 background: url(banner.jpg) no-repeat center -280px fixed;
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Now for testing purposes, I have uploaded 4 images through carrierwave and is stored in my database and is called upon through the instance variable @modelings. The issue arrises when I use the .each method. It will create 4 of the `<div ... id="banner1">` which is not what I want.

What I am trying to do is have the 1 `<div ... id="banner1">`, when clicked on, modal window will pop out with an image gallery of all the images stored in it. I've tried playing around with the ERB's location but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: this `<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<%= modeling.image %>">` is actually what (I think) is bound to fancybox, so you would need to bind a `click` event to the `#banner1` selector that should trigger a `click` on the first `.fancybox` selector like `$("#banner1").click(function(){$(".fancybox").eq(0).click()});`. Of course, it's assumed that you also have the `$(".fancybox").fancybox()` init.

Comment: @JFK thanks for your quick response, yes the class "fancybox" is what is actually triggering the modal window. The javascript i have now is simply `$(document).ready(function({$(".fancybox").fancybox({openEffect :'none', closeEffect :'none'});});` which is enough to trigger the modal window and show the images that are stored. That opens up fine, what my issue is the repeating of the `<div ... id="banner1">`

Comment: I guess you need to remove `<div ... id="banner1">` OUT of the `<a class="fancybox">` tag

Answer (score 1):

Its seems like you are duplicating the ids in `<div class="small-11 small-centered columns banner" id="banner1">`. and because of that fancybox cannot identified which image to load.

Try to make the id dynamic , something like

`<div class="small-11 small-centered columns banner" id="banner<%= modeling.id %>">` and call the java script accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your response, with the code I currently have, even though it will produce the `<div class="small-11 small-centered columns banner" id="banner1">` 4 times, once I click into it, my stored images are actually there. I just can't seem to get rid of the reproduction of `<div class="small-11 small-centered columns banner" id="banner1">`. I've tied your solution as well and that reproduced the H1 tag instead. :/